# Kafka Stream - lookup by customer name and related info from the topics

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-streams, debezium

[Kafka Stream lookup customer by value architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgh8U.png)

From the above problem statement  diagram ,the requirement is to fetch the attr1 and attr2 based on the incoming message containing customer: "XYZ".

```
customer
-------
customer_id,
customer_name

customer_config
---------------
customer_id,
attr1,
attr2,

cust_agg
--------
customer_id,
customer_name,
attr1,
attr2,

**since i use debezium and while cust rec delete,we dont get old value
 null means tombstone.
 so i am using custagggobj to get prev value,and after rekey,i will 
 push to same topic cust-agg-topic ,is it a good way to code.i think that new key and value will be synced to all instances of the app. since any cust_name falls in specific partitions, consequent updates are reflected eventually.**    

cust globalstore = fetch from customer topic 
custcfg globalstore=fetch from customer-config topic9
custagg global store= fetch from cust-agg-topic topic  // fetch    from the topic (1) 

// kstream tocustomeraggtopic = 
transform(custgstore,custcfgstore,custaggstore);
{


custobj= ctx.get(custgstore) # customer_id is key 
custcfgobj =ctx.get(custcfgstore) # customer_id is key 
custagggobj = ctx.get(custagggstore) # customer_name is key 

custaggkey = custagg(cust_name);  # use cust name as key
custaggvalue = custagg(cust,custcfg);
return KeyValue.pair(custaggkey, custaggvalue );
} 

tocustomeraggtopic.to("cust-agg-topic")  // update to the same topic (1)
```

Comment: Just so we're clear: You don't have access to customer_id in the "incoming data"?

Comment: @Emil: i have access to customer_id , but lookup key should be done on customer name.

Comment: I don't understand why the lookup, specifically, has to be on customer name if you have access to the customer_id. Unless the names are unique the lookup will have to return multiple results.

Comment: @Emil: I am sorry , i understood different, the incoming data only has customer name .

Comment: In your picture the data flows _from_ the tables _into_ kafka, right to left?

You then have some other incoming data in the kafka streams app that you want to enrich using the data from the kafka topics `customer` and `customer-config`?

Comment: @Emil: yes you are right .need to enrich data from customer and customer-config. Using customer name.

Comment: @Emil: any idea